# What is a real-world usage for Prototype pattern in Java?

Tags: design-patterns

After having studied GoF Prototype pattern and taken a look into Java implementation using the `Object#clone()` method I am still confused about when to use this pattern in a real application?

Please, provide some use-cases from Java applications, frameworks, etc. if there are any.

Comment: Real world application:  You need to create a spreadsheet containing many cells.  Each cell has its own style which you also must set.  You use prototype pattern to create a template cell so you can only make minor adjustments on each cell, rather than necessarily change all the style settings each and every time.

Comment: @Neil It is a really good example - I haven't thought of it (I was thinking within the enterprise context). Maybe you could make a full answer?

Comment: Ok, wrote you a formal answer.  Good luck to you!  :)

Comment: Almost nonexistant since `clone` is broken in Java. In 99% cases one uses classes (which are kind of "prototypes") with the `new` operator to get instances (or copy) of them.

Comment: @Spotted what do you mean by "broken"? you can avoid both the `clone` and `new` altogether using some sort of serialization, for instance

Comment: That's right but using `new` will always be the safer and more clear way to do, using `clone` or serialization will yield obscure code and can more easily lead to sneaky bugs. [Why clone is broken in Java](https://howtodoinjava.com/core-java/cloning/cloneable-interface-is-broken-in-java/)

Comment: @Spotted, ok, got your point

Comment: Here's an example from the GoF book itself: a GUI/application framework that provides a button control that creates application-specific objects (so the framework can't know what they are). The developers who use the framework plug-in into it by passing a prototypical instance to the button class, which can then return a clone when clicked, and the user can then change misc properties on the clone. Think of something like drag & drop controls in a form/window designer. Now imagine using the same framework to make a musical note editor, where buttons create various notes (the example GoF give).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Posting comment as answer (elaborated slightly):

A possible real world application might be say, when you need to create a spreadsheet containing many cells.  Rather than set the style for each newly created cell to override the default stylings, you'd use a Prototype pattern to create a template cell, and clone that cell when creating new cells.

This gives you the added advantage of say, expanding the template cell to create a version for showing dates, and another for showing numbers, without necessarily having to know the precise details of your template cell.  You'd simply clone the template cell, and perform whatever adjustment you require and use that as a specialized template.

It essentially allows you to set the details of the style in exactly one place in your program, and those changes persist with every new cell created without explicitly knowing how it is styled.

Apache Poi comes to mind, though you could easily apply the Protype pattern without the library necessarily supporting a clone method by creating a wrapper which does support clone.

Good luck!

Comment: So the operation would be apply style to the whole sheet? While I think this example follows the spirit of the pattern, I can think of other ways to implement it like creating a single style object and do copy-on-write when styling particular cells. That would be more similar to flyweight I think.

Comment: @DPM It wouldn't be flyweight, because ultimately each cell's style gets copied once added to the page, so you couldn't say change the style of all cells with that instance passed later (I may be mistaken, but I think that's how it works).  But yeah, you could do it this way as well.  Maybe there are better examples I could have used in this case.  Supposing you were dealing with an html element, you could implement prototype pattern to good effect without knowing or caring how that particular html tag is (it wouldn't be enough to simply reuse the same style in that instance for example).

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example from the GoF book itself. Suppose you are developing a GUI/application framework that, among other things, provides a button control that is designed to be a way to create *application-specific* objects. This means that the framework can't know what these objects are; instead it has to provide an extensibility mechanism, a way for client code to plug into it. One way to do it is to have the developers *who use the framework* (to create their own application) pass a prototypical instance to the button class. This then enables the button to simply return a clone when clicked, and the end user can then proceed to change various properties on the clone. Think of something like drag & drop controls in a form/window designer. Now imagine using the same framework to make a musical note editor, where buttons create various notes and other objects (which is the example the GoF book gives).

There are other interesting things you can do using this approach. Imagine some sort of a diagramming application. You can have your users create custom objects (custom-drawn shapes, or composite objects made out of different predefined shapes, etc.), and save that as a preset. Then you can load such a preset as a prototype into a button, and have the button clone it and place it on the canvas.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you must use full/big Object to method, for example `User` object which normally created using (costly) database query

In case you want to do batch execution of updating mass/many users with same details

Let's assume you need to send to DAO method the `User` object with same details (updating all users with same values) except id for each user.

Instead of create User (from database?) object every time you can clone object and update only its id.